# Получение данных столбцов таблицы A, на которые ссылаются данные столбцов таблицы B

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть две таблицы:

1. `products` со столбцами `id`, `name`, `type`
2. `types` со столбцами `id`, `type`

`products.type` является `foreign key` для `type.id`.

Нужно из таблицы `types` выбрать только те `type`, на чьи `id` ссылаются `products.type` без повторений `types.id` в выборке. Вот, что я уже написал и это вроде работает: ...

```
SELECT `t`.`type` 
FROM `types` `t` 
JOIN `products` `p` 
WHERE `t`.`id` = `p`.`type` 
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
```

... но т.к. с `MySql` я на Вы, то с большой вероятностью что-то сделал неправильно. Конкретно, есть следующие вопросы:

1. Насколько данный запрос производителен, какие комментарии?
2. Если заменить `WHERE` на `ON`, то все работает, так в чем разница?
3. Почему иногда кавычки ` используют, а иногда нет?
4. Что почитать на эту тему (онлайн ресурсы, книги)? (опционально)

Не стал разбивать на несколько отдельных вопросов т.к. ответ на некоторые можно дать одним предложением. В ответе прошу разобрать каждый вопрос.

Comment: 1) В общем случае запрос синтаксически некорректен. 2) В данном случае ни в чём. 3) Если не знаешь, когда их не-использование приведёт к проблеме - используй всегда. 4) Официальную документацию. *В ответе прошу разобрать каждый вопрос.* Репетиторство - во фрилансе.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответ. Интересует фраза `синтаксически некорректен`. Не могли бы вы подробнее рассказать, в чем / где именно.

Comment: Почитайте про ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: @Akina, здесь подробная инструкция, как решить проблему, связанную с этим бессмысленным нововведением: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983/10306509

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Это не "бессмысленное нововведение", а устранение отклонения от стандарта. Для адептов безалаберного программирования - отключаемое. Достаточно того, что при неполной группировке результат запроса недетерминирован.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Вот простейший пример: [fiddle](https://rextester.com/CIDY74465)

Comment: @Akina, по-видимому, на каком-то этапе мы не совсем поняли друг друга. Я ничего не имею против обработки полного перечня полей при группировке. Иногда это действительно необходимо. И до MySQL 5.7.5 никто не запрещал этого делать. Но я категорически против того, чтобы это превращалось в **требование** и становилось обязательным даже в тех случаях, когда в этом нет необходимости. Насчет "безалаберного программирования" Вы не правы. Такой подход вполне четко описан в стандарте SQL:1999, в отличие от стандарта SQL-92, на который опираетесь Вы (и MySQL 5.7.5+). Но не будем начинать религиозный спор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте попробуем составить запрос "с нуля".
Итак, мы имеем классическое отношение "один-ко-многим". Сделаем под это дело полный **LEFT JOIN** для получения всех строк **`types`**, которые как-то использует таблица **`products`**:

```
SELECT `types`.*
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
```

Собственно, теперь мы имеем полную выборку всех нужных нам строк из **`types`** с одной небольшой проблемой: у нас возможна многократная повторная выдача одних и тех же строк.
Решаем эту проблему просто:

```
SELECT `types`.*
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
GROUP BY `types`.`id`
```

Собственно, все. Осталось только "причесать" этот запрос по вашему вкусу.
Если в результате нужен только столбец **`types`.`type`**, выбираем его вместо **`types`.***.
Если любите синонимы - делаете **`products` [AS] `p`** и **`types` [AS] `t`**.
Если не любите обратные кавычки - смело их убирайте, в данном случае они не нужны, т.к. в именах столбцов нет ничего, что нужно экранировать.
Лично я бы кавычки оставил - это хорошая практика, и синонимы не применял бы: в таком простом запросе они не нужны.

Обратите внимание на использование **LEFT JOIN**'а, направленного в правильную сторону. Это ключевое отличие предлагаемого варианта запроса от первоначального.

***Update:***
[Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) обратил внимание на то, что возможны ситуации, при которых таблица **`products`** будет ссылаться на несуществующий элемент таблицы **`types`**.
В принципе, таких ситуаций необходимо избегать на этапе заполнения/редактирования таблиц. Для этого в MySQL есть целый ряд инструментов (например, [**FOREIGN KEY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)), но если такая неконсистентность базы все-таки по каким-либо причинам допустима, необходимо добавить дополнительную фильтрацию результата. Сделать это можно, например, так:

```
SELECT `types`.`type`
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
GROUP BY `types`.`id`, `types`.`type`
HAVING `types`.`type` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: :facepalm: Опять неполная группировка. Почти наверняка лишняя запись в выдаче (из одних NULLов). И вообще - несоответствие заданию.

Comment: @Akina, я не часто слышу подобные заявления в адрес своего кода, поэтому не поленился, создал минимальные тестовые таблицы и выполнил на них приведенный в моем ответе SQL-запрос. Результат именно тот, который ожидал автор вопроса: **"из таблицы types выбрать только те type, на чьи id ссылаются products.type без повторений types.id в выборке."**. Если у вас есть сомнения в моем коде, пожалуйста, приведите минимальный пример таблицы, при выборке из которой результат будет неправильным.

Comment: Минимальное заполнение таблиц в моем тесте: INSERT INTO `types` (`id`, `type`) VALUES ('1', 'type1'), ('2', 'type2'), ('3', 'type3'); INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES ('1', 'product1', '1'), ('2', 'product2', '1'), ('1', 'product3', '3'); Запрос: SELECT `types`.`type`
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `types`
ON `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`
GROUP BY `types`.`id` Результат: type1
type3

Comment: На всякий случай, версия тестового сервера:MySQL 5.5.58-0+deb8u1.

Comment: Добавьте в таблицу продуктов запись, не имеющую соотв. записи в таблице типов.

Comment: @Akina, мне кажется, что таких ситуаций следует избегать в принципе. Но на случай, если подобная вероятность все-таки есть, я добавил небольшое дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Рассмотрите замену LEFT JOIN на просто напрашивающийся в данном случае INNER JOIN. А заодно - чисто для себя,- попробуйте  себе (именно себе, а не мне, автору или ещё кому) доказать, что LEFT JOIN необходим, и доказать же, что любой другой JOIN не подходит. Мне кажется, это вам совершенно необходимо сделать.

Comment: @Akina, у этой задачи могут быть разные способы решения. Можно вообще обойтись без ключевых слов **JOIN**, **ON** и **GROUP BY**, например, так: `SELECT DISTINCT \`types\`.\`type\`
FROM \`products\`, \`types\`
WHERE \`products\`.\`type\` = \`types\`.\`id\``. Отличия в результате будут проявляться только в том случае, если в таблице  `\`types\`` есть строки с одинаковыми значениями `\`type\`` для разных `\`id\``

Comment: Я не о том. Кстати, последний запрос - это INNER JOIN в формате картезианского произведения. Тогда как Вы в своём ответе акцентировались на именно LEFT. Я о том, что у Вас прослеживается плохая тенденция - "давайте влепим LEFT, и пофиг на логику, потом подкорректируем". Я специально Вам дал условия, когда некорректность LEFT вылезает наружу - а Вы вместо корректировки подхода понесли пургу насчёт "такое надо избегать", и даже внесли дополнительную ремарку в ответ. Вместо того, чтобы привести текст запроса в соответствие с требуемой логикой.

Comment: @Akina, Вы пишете много правильных вещей и всё было бы просто прекрасно, если бы при этом Вы более корректно относились к возможности существования подходов, отличных от Вашего. А так Вы в одной только теме успели отписаться и про "адептов безалаберного программирования", и про "пургу", и про многое другое. Хотя я буду продолжать настаивать на том, что поддержание корректности данных в БД необходимо контролировать на этапе модификации данных, а не на этапе выборки. В базу не должен вноситься продукт с не существующим типом, и не должен удаляться тип, используемый каким-либо продуктом.

Comment: Вы использовали в своём ответе LEFT JOIN. **Это - ошибка.** Логика требует INNER JOIN. *я буду продолжать настаивать на том, что поддержание корректности данных в БД необходимо контролировать на этапе модификации данных, а не на этапе выборки.* Это более чем спорное утверждение. Поддержание корректности должно закладываться в первую очередь на этапе проектирования - соответствующими ограничениями структуры хранения данных, которые просто не позволят вносить некорректные изменения.

Comment: LEFT JOIN это **НЕ** ошибка. Это вариант решения задачи. Который быстро работает и дает правильный результат. Опубликуйте Ваш вариант решения и если он будет действительно хорош, я лично с удовольствием проголосую за него, даже если буду считать, что мой вариант лучше. Просто потому, что разные подходы - это НОРМАЛЬНО. А насчет этапа модификации - да, разумеется, запрет неправильной модификации необходимо закладывать на этапе проектирования. Собственно об этом я и написал в позавчерашнем дополнении к моему ответу, когда упоминал про FOREIGN KEY. Просто я не счел нужным повторять это еще раз

Comment: *LEFT JOIN это НЕ ошибка.* Да, формально всё равно, что использовать - `INNER JOIN` или `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NOT NULL`. Но 1) Запрос, не соответствующий логике - неверный, даже когда в частном случае даёт верный результат; 2) Зачем заставлять сервер выполнять заведомо лишнюю работу?

Comment: @Akina, я исходил из того, что все строки таблицы `\`products\`` ссылаются на существующие элементы таблицы `\`types\``, т.е. в изначальную выборку должны входить все без исключения элементы таблицы `\`products\``, для каждого из которых СУБД должна найти соответствующий элемент таблицы `\`types\``. Это минимальный набор данных, меньше которого для достижения цели сделать нельзя. При выборке, СУБД сразу же проверяет условие `\`products\`.\`type\` = \`types\`.\`id\``, и отбрасывает ненужные строки, т.е. никакая лишняя работа не делается.

Comment: *я исходил из того, что* Вот именно. INNER JOIN обеспечивает выполнение этого условия вне зависимости от того, соответствуют ли ему данные в таблицах или нет. В то время как LEFT JOIN требует дополнительной корректировки, если НЕ соответствуют. *При выборке, СУБД сразу же проверяет условие `products`.`type` = `types`.`id`, и отбрасывает ненужные строки* **НЕТ!!!** Нет никакого отбрасывания! Условие находится в секции ON, а не в секции WHERE! Вот эта фраза ещё раз подтверждает, что Вы не понимаете отличия LEFT от INNER. И именно разобраться и понять это различие я Вас и призываю.

Comment: @Akina, такое ощущение, что Вы просто пропускаете те моменты, в которых я пишу, что исхожу из начальной выборки ВСЕХ строк из таблицы `\`products\`` и соответствующих им элементов таблицы `\`types\``, а это - классический LEFT JOIN. Вы же предлагаете выбирать только НЕКОТОРЫЕ строки таблицы `\`products\``, предполагая, что не все из них имеют связь с существующими элементами в `\`types\``, т.е. описываете INNER JOIN. Поверьте, я прекрасно понимаю разницу между ними, но исхожу из того, что для решения данной  задачи нужен именно первый вариант, но при этом допускаю возможность и Вашего подхода.

Comment: *я пишу, что исхожу из начальной выборки ВСЕХ строк из таблицы `products`* Но Вы не отвечаете на вопрос "Зачем выбирать ВСЕ строки из этой таблицы, когда нужны только те, которые имеют соответствие? Почему не выбирать сразу только те, у которых соответствие имеется?". Ведь исходная задача требует именно этого: *Нужно из таблицы `types` выбрать **только те** `type`, на чьи `id` ссылаются `products.type`*...

Comment: @Akina, я исхожу из того, что нужно выбрать ВСЕ строки из таблицы `\`products\`` (потому что среди них НЕТ тех, которые не ссылались бы на реально существующие элементы таблицы `\`types\`` - в моем варианте это критерий построения архитектуры базы) и лишь некоторые элементы из таблицы `\`types\``, которые соответствуют условию задачи. Если одну из двух связанных таблицы мы выбираем целиком, а вторую частично, это и есть классический LEFT JOIN. Вы же исходите из того, что не все элементы таблицы `\`products\`` могут иметь связи с `\`types\`` и предлагаете выбирать их пересечение (INNER JOIN).

Comment: *Вы же исходите из того, что* Я исхожу из задачи. Которая не устанавливает, есть ли непривязанные данные, и требует вывода только привязанных данных. Что и требует внутреннего соединения. И INNER JOIN выбирает сразу только привязанные данные и отсеивает непривязанные, если таковые имеются. Уже на стадии связывания таблиц. Вы же выбираете все, и только затем на стадии пост-отбора отсеиваете непривязанные данные - т.е. в общем случае сервер сперва должен добавить NULL-записи зависимой таблицы, а потом отбросить их. Лишняя, ненужная работа. Которую сервер обязан выполнить - запрос такой.

Comment: @Akina, в задаче ничего не сказано о том, что некоторые продукты могут ссылаться на несуществующие типы. Соответственно, я исхожу из того, что нам придется выбрать ВСЕ продукты. А пример с последующей фильтрацией я привел только в качестве демонстрации того, как можно МИНИМАЛЬНО модифицировать УЖЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩЕЕ решение. P.S.: На этом этапе было бы хорошо, если бы к нашему диалогу присоединился автор вопроса и уточнил условия задачи: могут ли в таблице продуктов быть элементы, не ссылающиеся на существующие элемента таблицы типов?

Comment: *в задаче ничего не сказано о том* Именно. Всё, что не описано явно, может быть как угодно. То есть непривязанные записи могут быть, могут не быть - это не указано. Следовательно, надо учитывать и тот, и другой варианты. *я привел только в качестве демонстрации того, как можно МИНИМАЛЬНО модифицировать УЖЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩЕЕ решение* Неужели Вы не видите, что условие по левой таблице в модифицированном решении приводит к вырождению стороннего связывания во внутреннее?

Comment: @Akina, вижу, конечно. Но я в принципе не считаю это решение целевым. В моем постинге оно приведено лишь в качестве небольшой модификации моего изначального решения. А что касается постановки задачи, то тут никто не сможет нас рассудить, кроме автора вопроса.